# folder picker crash in windows 8.1 app

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

in my windows 8.1 im trying to show folder picker but it ends with crash(debugger break in App.g.i.cs file).

here is the code im using for folder picker:

```
FolderPicker openFP = new FolderPicker();
openFP.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openFP.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFolder SF = await openFP.PickSingleFolderAsync();          StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", SF);
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), SF.Name);
```

please give me any solutions

Comment: Can you debug it to see if the 'SF' is null?

Comment: i get folder picker by adding filter type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got folder picker by adding filter type in code
code:

```
FolderPicker openFP = new FolderPicker();
openFP.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
openFP.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
openFP.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
openFP.FileTypeFilter.Add(".gif");
openFP.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
StorageFolder SF = await openFP.PickSingleFolderAsync();    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", SF);
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), SF.Name);
```